# How to perform following query in LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

I have a SQL query need to do in LINQ. Can anyone helps in converting?

```
SELECT * 
FROM profile 
WHERE ProfileId <> 1221 AND IsActive = 1 AND
      ProfileId NOT IN (SELECT ReportingPerson 
                        FROM ReportingPersons 
                        WHERE Employee = 1221)
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390126/is-there-a-not-in-sub-query-for-linq-to-enties-as-in-this-t-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     var reportingPerson = context.ReportingPersons.Where(x => 
                           x.Employee == 1221)
                           .Select(c => c.ReportingPerson
                           ).ToList();

     var result = context.Profiles
                         .Where(x => 
                                x.ProfileId != 1221 && 
                                x.IsActive && 
                                !reportingPerson.Contains(x.ProfileId)
                         .ToList();
```